# CentOS 6 | bash_profile giving errors?

Tags: centos, bash

I have a .bash_profile, and its giving me an error "Unexpected end of file" I have no clue whats wrong, here it is,

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
export PS1="\u@\h\\$"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

It shows syntax error at line 11. But there is no line 11?...

Also, its not setting my ps1, but I'm supposing thats because the unexpected end of file.

Comment: Do you write it on the Windows and upload to the Linux?

Comment: @quanta Yes. Using dreamweaver

Comment: I just tried seeing if there was an extra line using the vi command, but it showed only 10 lines. Very weird.

Comment: Google: Windows vs. Linux newline.

Comment: @quanta Thanks, but I don't understand, even in vi editor it shows only 10 lines?

Comment: Google: How to show special characters in `vi`.

Comment: Whilst bash is generally considered topical here, using dreamweaver on windows and uploading to unix isn't something a sysadmin would do. You'll probably find the answer to your dilema [here](http://serverfault.com/search?q=dos2unix).

Answer (score 2):

So, I believe there are special characters in your file.

You can check the same by using `vim`, instead of `vi`

Or if you open the file in vi, you can use this command to see the special characters.

```
:set list
```

After fixing it, you can use this command to get back to normal viewing mode

```
:set nolist
```

Once you remove the special characters, it should work fine.

Also, if you have emacs installed, that can also help you in the same, though I love vim and would always like to stick with that :)